# Magento 2 : Get image file from custom_option folder

Tags: magento2, custom-options, rest-api, quoteitem, media-images

I have a custom option of type file where I am allowing user to upload photo while adding a product to cart.

I am using the REST api to get the cart items. Below is the response for the same.

```
[
    {
        "item_id": 525,
        "sku": "782-169",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "simple product 1",
        "price": 0,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "538",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "3",
                        "option_value": "image/png,photosample.png,/var/www/html/magento2/pub/media/custom_options/quote/p/h/photosample.png,custom_options/quote/p/h/photosample.png,custom_options/quote/p/h/photosample.png,457,40,40,700e78d4f014ef0da997"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

URL I am using to fetch the image is : http://local.magento2.com/media/custom_options/quote/p/h/photosample.png

It gives me 404 error. I also tried below urls
http://local.magento2.com/media/customoptions/quote/p/h/photosample.png
http://local.magento2.com/media/custom_options/quote/p/h/700e78d4f014ef0da997

But same error I am getting. Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the pub/media/custom_options/.htaccess and commented the two lines. It is working for me now.
If anyone having better solutions please let me know.